# Since when does joking in chat result in suspension?

Tags: discussion, chat, account-suspension

In chat I made a joke after someone said "sorry".  I replied with the classic "you better be sorry" and was suspended for 30 minutes.

How is this just, when I was merely making a joke.  What rules in the chat forbid me from making such a statement?

Comment: That sounds like a suspension after the message was flagged by several users. [How do chat suspensions work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86479/how-do-chat-suspensions-work)

Comment: When reading words of a screen, it can be hard to judge whether someone is joking or just being rude...

Comment: @SBareS, so does that mean we should suspend just in case they are being rude, or rather give benefit of the doubt since it is up to interpretation.  And furthermore should rudeness lead to suspension?

Comment: I have not looked into the details of this situation, but it does seem reasonable to suspend people on chat for 30 minutes for being rude. The goal should be to have a relatively professional environment. Unfortunately, humor does not always come through with text-based communication.

Comment: The moderation in the chat is atrocious, and flagged messages get judged completely out of context by people who are probably not even in the room.

Comment: Smiley faces have to be included if your intention is to joke ;). Otherwise your post should be dripping with sarcasm. In your case neither of these two cases fit, so your statement was ambiguous. However, I have to say that just like voting on this site, there are collections of people who just go around looking for things to upvote/downvote without actually participating. In your case you got the later...

Comment: @Zach466920 So it's not just me that's realized there's a large number of people that go around downvoting content without caring to leave a comment explaining why they downvoted and how the poster can improve their content.